# DynamoDb Filter expression not working on Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am trying to filter my scan result using multiple filter expression values in a lambda function but encountering an error.

Lambda Function:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler =  (event, context) => {

   var params = {
   TableName : "4298.Dev.Log_OnP.RecruitingDemandOrders",
   FilterExpression: ("#DFC <> Recruiting"
                    ,"#DS = :FI"
                    ,"#ETA = :FA"
                    ),
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#DS": "demand.status"
        ,"#DFC":"demand.fulfillmentChannel3"
        ,"#ETA":"exportedToATAS"

   },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":FA": {"S" : "false"}
        ,":FI":{"S" : "Filled"}
        }

   }

    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {

        if( err ) {
          console.log('dynamoProcessor-getdemandRecord ERROR' + err);
        } else {

                    for (var i in data.Items) {
            i = data.Items[i];
            console.log(i);
            context.done(null, "Ciao!");
        }
                    }
});

}
```

Error:
Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#DS,  #DFC}

Did I write the correct filter expression?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting your `FilterExpression` value incorrectly. It should be a single string, using the same syntax as a `ConditionalExpression`. The syntax is defined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html).

Try changing it to this:

```
FilterExpression: "#DFC <> Recruiting AND #DS = :FI AND ETA = :FA",
```